# TEXT IS NOT PRINTING IN CONSOLE IN SELENIUM

Tags: java, selenium

I need help please why isnt this printing text in the console it is only showing the number of elements but not text PLEASE HELP

```
List<WebElement> allLinks= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@aria-label,'main-menu, Collections, Football')]"));
    System.out.println(allLinks.size());
    Thread.sleep(2000);

for(WebElement a: allLinks) {
    System.out.println(a.getText());
```

Comment: may be they do not have any text contained in them? Can you share the link or HTML DOM snapshot here?

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML.

Comment: Try with: System.out.println(a.getAttribute('innerHTML'));  Might tell you something...